# require from parent directory does not work on hoster

Tags: php

I currently want to deploy a php app to a shared hoster. Sadly it seems that the require function can not access the parent directory to include a file. This only works locally. I created a minimum working example:

directory structure:

```
/project/bootstrap/app.php
/project/public/index.php
```

app.php:

```
<?php

print("Hello from app");
```

index.php:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';

print('Hello World!');
```

The app works perfectly fine locally, while on the server I get a 'HTTP ERROR 500'. I checked the folder and file permissions on the server and they are set to 755 for folders and 644 for files.

Edit: When I activate error reporting I get the following errors:

```
Warning: require(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/path/on/hoster/bootstrap/app.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/path/on/hoster/public/:/tmp/) in /path/on/hoster/public/index.php on line 6

Warning: require(/path/on/hoster/bootstrap/app.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /path/on/hoster/public/index.php on line 6

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/path/on/hoster/public/../bootstrap/app.php' (include_path='.:/opt/plesk/php/7.2/share/pear') in /path/on/hoster/public/index.php on line 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your hosting is using an older PHP version.

Check this code:

```
<?php

require realpath( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../bootstrap/app.php' );

print('Hello World!');
```

or simply do like this:

```
require  '../bootstrap/app.php';
```

### UPDATE

If you can't see any error, then enable PHP's Error reporting by adding these lines to the top of your code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The hosting and my local PHP version are the same (PHP 7.2). I tried your code anyways but it is still the same problem. It works locally but not on the hoster.

Comment: @JuarX Is PHP error reporting on? can you see any error on your screen?

Comment: I just added error reporting to my code and updated my original post with the errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. When analyzing the error message, I found out that I have to change the open_basedir setting in the php.ini file. My hoster provides a graphical interface for editing the php.ini file, so it was easy to change open_basedir from 'Yes' to 'No'.